# Can I "lock" icons in the dock?

Tags: plank

I have lost count of times I have accidentally removed an icon from the dock by being a "bit too fast/sloppy" with my mouse movement (swiping an icon away from the dock removes it from the dock). It is beginning to irritate me :-)
Is it possible "to lock" the the icons in the dock (and/or only allow removing of them by mouse's right click action) ???
Please :-)

Comment: Check settings mouse, maybe there is something there. I dont get that so I can compare mine. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl + Right click on Plank opens a menu. There you can find Preferences -> Behaviour -> Lock Icons and select it.

Comment: Solved, thank you @Webshaped